# Trying to populate <keyword> in urlpattern

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

So my goal is to populate the keyword `<category>` in urls.py to make a dynamic url pattern. When I click on a post in BoxesView ,my urlpattern is still `http://127.0.0.1:8000/1/1/` and not `http://127.0.0.1:8000/news/1/` like I want it to be.

What's causing me most of my problems is django forcing me to use a tuple for my CATEGORY_CHOICES, as opposed to a list. And for some reason it only allows the number (e.g. '1', '2') to be used in my arguments and not 'news', 'sport' etc. so in my `article` function in views.py, `name` has to be the number, regardless if the number is in the 1st or second part of the tuple brackets.

Also with this in my template:

```
<a href="{% url 'article' category=post.category id=post.id %}">
```

because of the problem I stated above, post.category here will always be the number and not the word. Which I believe is messing with my category keyword in `(?P<category>\w+)`.

Here's my code:

**choices.py**

```
CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
('news', '1'),
('sport', '2'),
('technology', '3'),
('science', '4'),
('cars', '5')
```

)

**urls.py**

```
BV = BoxesView.as_view()

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^news/', BV, name='news'),
url(r'^sport/', BV, name='sport'),
url(r'^technology/', BV, name='technology'),
url(r'^science/', BV, name='science'),
url(r'^(?P<category>\w+)/(?P<id>\d+)/', article, name='article'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
class BoxesView(ListView):
template_name = 'polls.html'

def get_queryset(self):
    for a, b in CATEGORY_CHOICES:
        name = resolve(self.request.path_info).url_name
        if a == name:
            category = b
            print(category) # '1', '2' etc
            queryset_list = Post.objects.all().filter(category=category).order_by('-date')
        return queryset_list


def article(request, id, category):
name = resolve(request.path).kwargs['category']
for a, b in CATEGORY_CHOICES:
    if b == name:
        name = b
        print(name) # '1', '2' etc
instance = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id, category=name)

queryset = Post.objects.all()
context = {
    'object_list': queryset,
    'instance': instance
}
return render(request, 'article.html', context)
```

**template.html**

```
<a href="{% url 'article' category=post.category id=post.id %}">
```

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
category = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, default='1')

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return '/%s/%s/' % (self.get_category_display, self.id)
```

So i'm still unsure what I have to do exactly to make the urlpattern keyword `<category>` work. (By the way, the `<id>` keyword works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The choices should be like this.

```
CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
    ('1','news'),
    ('2','sport'),
    ('3','technology'),
    ('4','science'),
    ('5','cars'), )
```

Comment: i've tried that aswell, for some reason i can still only use the number

Comment: Also change in template.
<a href="{% url 'article' category=post.get_category_display id=post.id %}">

Comment: Ok so I just added that code in^, and it returns the correct url:but when I click on a post now it doesn't go to the `article` it just

Comment: -it just returns the same view. So it doesn't change the view but the url is correct (http://127.0.0.1:8000/news/1/)

Comment: I think you have to change database entries too. :(

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: in your views file, the parameter order seems incorrect, it should be like this 
def article(request,category, id):

Comment: Fixed. but also the `category` parameter is grey (using Pycharm so it's telling me it's not being used). Any idea?

Comment: Actually, It's looking for a variable, but we have used it as dictionary key.

Comment: Where does it find the variable from? And how have we used it as a dictionary key? Also, why is this any different from `id`? They're used the exact same way.

Comment: in your views file.

def article(request, id, category):
name = resolve(request.path).kwargs['category']
for a, b in CATEGORY_CHOICES:
    if b == name:
        name = b
        print(name) # '1', '2' etc
instance = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id, category=name)

you used id directly
instance = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id, category=name)

and category
name = resolve(request.path).kwargs['category']

Comment: Right. So you said id works because it was used directly? So should I change this or leave as is?:  instance = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id, category=name)